# how to render quickreplies in react-native-gifted chat?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using `react-native-gifted-chat` for chat UI in my project and I am looking for how to use `renderQuickReplies` and `QuickReplySend` function in react-native.

```
<GiftedChat
  messages={messages}
  placeholder="Any pick-up notes?"
  onSend={messages => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'private_message',
      data: {
        message: messages[0],
        conversationId: userId,
      },
    });
    dispatch({
      type: 'server/private_message',
      data: {message: messages[0], conversationId: userId},
    });
  }}
  renderBubble={renderBubble}
  renderSend={renderSend}
  isTyping={true}
  renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
  renderAvatar={renderAvatar}
  scrollToBottom={true}
  renderQuickReplies={renderQuickReplies(quickReplies)}
  alignTop={true}
  user={{
    _id: selfUser.userId,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use renderQuickreplies in `renderBubble` prop. If you want to customize the chat components it can get REALLY complicated. But here's my example of how it might look:

I use custom message type extended from default Gifted Chat's message:

```
type MessageType =
  | 'TEXT'
  | 'AMOUNT_SLIDER'
  | 'ERROR'
  | 'WARNING'
  | 'SCROLL_PICKER'
  | 'IMAGE_BUBBLE_USER'
  | 'FILE_BUBBLE_USER'
  | 'FILE_SELECT'
  | 'QUICKREPLIES'
  | 'DATE';

export interface ChatMessage extends IMessage {
  type: MessageType; //<- important part

  sliderConfig?: SliderConfig;
  dateConfig?: DateConfig;
  imageConfig?: {
    uri: string;
  };
  fileConfig?: {
    uri: string;
    name: string;
  };
  scrollOptions?: ScrollOption[];
  cameraConfig?: {
    type: 'front' | 'back';
  };
  quickReplies?: BotQuickReplies;
  onClick?: () => void;

  //..other props
}
```

GiftedChat:

```
//... other code
    <GiftedChat
        //...other props
        messages={IMessages} //pass my custom messages array
        renderBubble={(props: any) => (
          <RenderComponents
            props={props}
            onQuickReply={onQuickReply}
            setInput={setInput}
            onTextChange={onTextChange}
            locale={locale}
            stepConfig={stepConfig}
            IMessages={IMessages}
            setIMessages={setIMessages}
            openCamera={openCamera}
            onComponentFinishedRendering={onComponentFinishedRendering}
            removeErrors={removeErrors}
            pushUserMessage={pushUserAnswer}
          />
        )}
        //...other props
     />
//...other code
```

RenderComponents:

```
//...other code
const RenderComponents: React.FC<Props> = ({
  props: giftedChatProps,
  onQuickReply,
  setInput,
  onTextChange,
  locale,
  stepConfig,
  IMessages,
  setIMessages,
  openCamera,
  onComponentFinishedRendering,
  removeErrors,
  pushUserMessage,
}) => {
 //...other code
const { currentMessage } = giftedChatProps;
const { type, _id } = currentMessage as ChatMessage;

switch (type) {
    case 'SCROLL_PICKER': {
      return (
        <CustomScrollPicker
          //...props
        />
      );
    }
    case 'ERROR': {
      return (
        <ErrorBubble
          //...props
        />
      );
    }
//...other message types

case 'QUICKREPLIES': {
  return (
    <QuickRepliesController
      onQuickReply={onQuickReply}
      quickReplies={currentMessage.quickReplies}
      //...other props
    />
  );
}
//...other message types
default: {
  return null;
}
```

}
};

export default RenderComponents;

and finally the custom Chat message bubble for when the message type is 'QUICKREPLIES' , it goes through another animation layer which i will not be copying here, its just bunch of animation functions, but finally renders this Component which is basically just a View box with some custom styled Buttons:

```
//...other code
const QuickRepliesBubble: FC<Props> = ({
  quickReplies, //quickreplies array from message object
  onQuickReply, // 
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {quickReplies.values.map((reply: BotReply) => {
        return (
          <CustomQuickReply 
            image={reply.image}
            key={reply.value}
            title={reply.localizedTitle}
            onPress={() =>
              onQuickReply({
                value: reply.value,
              })
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

I know that this might look like bunch of blocks of code. But the underlying idea is that you can completely custom render the `renderBubble` prop in GiftedChat component. but you need to figure out a way to switch between default bubbles and the ones that you have custom created. in my case i added 'type' property to my messge object and made a switch for different types of messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply to this issue. This seems pretty complicated. From looking at the Gifted Chat main readme, it looks like quick replies should render automatically if present, similar to system & user info. Is there a more straight forward way to do this?

Comment: ye, just do how it is in documentation, from what i gathered in your question i figured you need to figure out how to customize things... if you like everything how it is by default, just use default api.

Comment: is there any documentation which includes all the function definition of react-native-gifted-chat?